Spark Streaming: Periodic Latency Spike w/ ElasticSearch/OpenSearch Connector using Spark DataSource V2
I developed Spark Structured Streaming on Spark 3.1.2.
It reads streaming data and join with static DataFrame, which refreshes with a period using Delta foramt.
It sinks to ElasticSearch(or OpenSearch) w/ connector using DataSource V2 API.
(ElasticSearch-Hadoop/OpenSearch-Hadoop, ElasticSearch-Spark/OpenSearch-Spark)
But when i tried w/ DataSource V2 API, it showed periodic latency spike.

// DataSource V2 API
        val osFormatQuery = df
          .writeStream
          .outputMode("append")
          .queryName("writing_to_OpenSearch")
          .format("org.opensearch.spark.sql")
          .option("checkpointLocation", "hdfs://??")
          .option("inferSchema", "true")
          .option("opensearch.nodes", endpoint)
          .option("opensearch.net.http.auth.user", "??")
          .option("opensearch.net.http.auth.pass", "??")
          .option("opensearch.mapping.id", "doc_id")
          .option("opensearch.write.operation", "upsert")
          .option("opensearch.nodes.wan.only","true")
          .option("opensearch.nodes.discovery", "false")
          .trigger(org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
          .start(index)

At first, i've thought something's wrong with ElasticSearch/OpenSearch, but when i tried w/ .foreachBatch() and upload batch API, it does not appear.
// foreachBatch + Batch API
        val osQuery = df
          .writeStream
          .queryName("OpenSearch Bulk Update")
          .option("truncate", "false")
          .format("console")
          .option("checkpointLocation", "??")
          .trigger(org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
          .outputMode("append")
          .foreachBatch { 
            (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>

                .format("org.opensearch.spark.sql")
                .option("inferSchema", "true")
                .option("opensearch.nodes", endpoint)
                .option("opensearch.port", "80")
                .option("opensearch.resource", index)
                .option("opensearch.net.http.auth.user", "??")
                .option("opensearch.net.http.auth.pass", "??")
                .option("opensearch.mapping.id", "doc_id")
                .option("opensearch.write.operation", "upsert")
                .option("opensearch.nodes.wan.only","true")
                .option("opensearch.nodes.discovery", "false")
                .mode("append")
                .save()
          }
          .start()

Regardless of streaming batch interval size, it shows latency spike on every 5,6th batch.
I've thought it's only ElasticSearch's problem, but it shows the same in OpenSearch, too

but after i use foreachBatch and batch API,

In addition, It does not appear when the streaming data size is really small.

c.f.,
I report the issue on elasticsearch-hadoop community, but still no answer
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/2165
Anyone who had the same issue or guess the underlying cause ?
Thank you
